# Flask-Moment not displaying anything on template

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I have a template, named *user.html*, w/ this line of code:

```
<p>Member since {{ moment(user.member_since).format('L') }}. Last seen {{ moment(user.last_seen).fromNow() }}.</p>
```

Which renders the following page:

[image]

It looks like it's not rendering anything, yet looking at the source code of that same page:

[image]

...I can see my timestamps between  tags.

My question is: **What is stopping the browser from displaying my timestamp in the browser?**

---

Things to consider:

- I'm using Flask-Moment==0.5.1 (pulled straight from pip freeze command)
- I'm pulling the timestamp from a PostgreSQL database (image below)
- I'm following the *Flask Web Development* book, by Miguel Grinberg (pulled code straight from there)
- I've already checked the *Flask-Moment* github page and the *moment.js* documentation and found no answer to this question.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

---

*Timestamp registry in table*

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer to my question:

The template that needs to use *Flask-Moment* needs to contain the following lines:

```
{{ moment.include_jquery() }}
{{ moment.include_moment() }}
```

This wasn't in the book, yet I found the reference in the *The Flask Mega-Tutorial*, by the same author:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-moment-flask-and-jinja2-integration-with-momentjs

Comment: It should be mentioned that these directives need to be in the block containing the use of Moment.js. Putting them at the top-level did nothing for me.

Answer (score 3):

The times are not displayed as the is `style='display: none;'` in the tag. This will tell the browser to not display the tag. I don't know where it's comming from, but you should change it to `style='display: inline;'`.

Comment: Interesting. You do raise an excellent point. I'll see if I can find the origin of said style. Changing the style directly in the browser shows the corresponding timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

`flask-moment` requires your flask app to have access to both `jquery.com` and `cloudflare.com`. Make sure your browser extensions are not blocking access to external domains or you might see the same issue. Not that I'd ever do something so dumb. :-]